# Объдинить 2 списка

Tags: python

Как  объединенить 2 списка в один?

```
L1 = [0, 5]
L2 = [0, 10, 20]
```

Должно получиться:

```
L3 = [[0, 0], [0, 10], [0, 20], [5, 0], [5, 10], [5, 20]]
```

Comment: дубликаты где-то [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
l1 = [0, 5]
l2 = [0, 10, 20]
```

Первый вариант (самое простое решение, через вложенные циклы):

```
def combinate1(l1, l2):
    l3 = []
    for i in range(len(l1)):
        for j in range(len(l2)):
            l3.append([l1[i], l2[j]])
    return l3
```

Второй вариант (однострочный вариант предыдущего), через списковое включение:

```
def combinate2(l1, l2):
    return [[x, y] for i in l1 for j in l2]
```

Третий вариант (с помощью модуля itertools):

```
from itertools import product

def combinate3(l1, l2):
   return list(product(l1, l2))
```

Вывод:

```
[[0, 0], [0, 10], [0, 20], [5, 0], [5, 10], [5, 20]]
```

Подобная комбинация двух списков в математике называется ["прямым произведением"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) (Cartesian product).

Comment: Спасибо, Вам большое?

Comment: @JackSmith, если вам помог мой ответ, пожалуйста, примите его (галочка слева от ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Это не объединение, это декартово произведение. Декартово произведение списков — это набор всех возможных комбинаций элементов из каждого списка.
Декартово произведение списков можно сделать с помощью модуля itertools, который предоставляет функцию product. Эта функция возвращает декартово произведение входных итерабельных объектов как кортежи, а нужно получить список списков, немного поправим и получим:

```
import itertools

result = list(map(list,itertools.product([0,5],[10,20,30])))
print(result)
```

---

```
[[0, 10], [0, 20], [0, 30], [5, 10], [5, 20], [5, 30]]
```